# How to display changing text in Java Swing (ie, display time with changing seconds)

Tags: java, swing, date, time, jlabel

I'm looking for a way to display the current date and time on a JFrame as a JLabel but have it update automagically. Once it is drawn to the pane, I shouldn't need to worry about manually updating it because it will refresh say, every 2 seconds.

Is there a proper way of doing this? Instead of manually changing the JLabel's text value every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to ensure that updates to the Swing component occur on the EDT.

```
Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(2000, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        yourLabel.setText(...);
    }
});
t.start();
```

Comment: and with some examples for Timer http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Anappletthatcountsdownfromaspecifiedtime.htm

Answer (score 7):

Use Swing [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). As [the tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) explains, it is the required tool for the job.

The only alternative to their use is the embedding of a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` in a `TimerTask`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial