# jLabel's setText is not working even with SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm making a JLabel display a timer,so it is being updated every second and I'm updating it with the help of a thread I'm using SwingWorker to update the JLabel but it is not working.
Here is my code...

```
long pos=-1;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     try
    {
        pos=...value of timer....
        jLabel1.setText("in function");
        jLabel3.setText("in function");
        timer=new Thread(new adsa());
        timer.start();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {    
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT");
    }
}                                        

/**
 *
 */
public void run()
{

    try
    {

        System.out.println(pos);

    while(pos!=0 && clip.isRunning())
    {
        label1.setText(String.valueOf(pos));
        System.out.println(pos);
        pos--;
        timer.sleep(1000);

        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            public Object doInBackground(){

                try
                {
                jLabel3.setText(String.valueOf(pos));
                jLabel3.setText("ghfdxhc");
                label1.setText("hvgjh");
                System.out.println("zxc");

                return null;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        };
        worker.execute();
      }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in run");
    }
}
```

All the println statements are working,even the one's inside SwingWorker but jLabel is not being updated, "in function" is displayed on both labels and it is not changing.
Kindly suggest an alternative method if possible...

Comment: Try `repaint`ing the `JLabel` after setting the text.

Comment: Yikes..you've made things complicated. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330945/how-to-display-changing-text-in-java-swing-ie-display-time-with-changing-secon/6331033#6331033).

Comment: you should call `setText()` in `done()` rather than in `doInBackground()` im not sure if you will get update cause it's running in a diferent thread.. if you want to ensure `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run(){label.setText("123")} });`

Comment: Josh M-repaint didn't work...

Comment: mre-I have to use JLabel in thread coz the timer has to work for a long time and if I use it in a normal fashion with a button listener the button will remain pressed until JLabel is out of its loop

Comment: nachokk-I've already tried this method,it didn't work

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of work you should use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).  SwingWorker is ussually for heavy task and to don't block the gui([Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)) cause run in differents thread.

Im not sure if updating your gui in `doInBackground()` will be reflected as you know , it's run in another thread. To ensure you can

1) Wrap your call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)`

2) Using `publish(..)` and update here.

But i recommend to use for this task **Swing Timer**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a `Timer` to do this, but you need to run `setText` or any swing function in `Event dispatch thread`.

If you want to use SwingWorker you need to call swing function in EDT.
You can try something like this :

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            pos=...value of timer....
            jLabel1.setText("in function");
            jLabel3.setText("in function");
            Ctimer timer = new CTimer(pos, jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3);
            timer.execute();

    } 

    class CTimer extends SwingWorker<Void, Long> {

      private long pos;
      private JLabel jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3;

      public CTimer(long pos, JLabel jLabel1, JLabel jLabel2, JLabel jLabel3) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.jLabel1 = jLabel1;
        this.jLabel2 = jLabel2;
        this.jLabel3 = jLabel3;
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (pos != 0 && clip.isRunning()) {
          publish(pos);
          pos--;
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void process(List<Long> times) {
        for (Long time : times) {
          jLabel1.setText("xyz");
          jLabel2.setText("ababa");
          jLabel3.setText("" + time);
        }
      }
    }
```